# How to call web service in java script function

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Ar_PieChart.aspx.cs" Inherits="Ar_PieChart" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-16' />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-height,minimum-scale=0.5,maximum-scale=3.0,user-scalable=yes" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.load('visualization', '1', { packages: ['corechart'] });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                url: 'Ar_PieChart.aspx/bind_chartvalue',
                data: '{}',
                success:
                    function (response) {
                        drawVisualization(response.d);
                    }
            });
        })
        function drawVisualization(piedata) {
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', 'CLass');
            data.addColumn('int', 'count');
            for (var i = 0; i < piedata.length; i++) {
                data.addRow([piedata[i].CLass, piedata[i].count]);
            }
            new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).draw(data, { is3D: true });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="visualization" style="width: 600px; height: 350px">

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

code behind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Web.Services;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

public partial class Ar_PieChart : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        piedata.chart_data service = new piedata.chart_data();
        service.bind_chartvalue();

    }
}
```

My webservice

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using MySql.Data;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for chart_data
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class chart_data : System.Web.Services.WebService {

    MySqlConnection connectionString = new MySqlConnection("server=****;user id=****;Password=*****;database=****;");

    public chart_data () {

        //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
        //InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public List<chart> bind_chartvalue()
    {
        List<chart> chart = new List<chart>();

        connectionString.Open();
        MySqlCommand command = connectionString.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = "Select Class,COUNT(Class) AS COUNT from sh_report GROUP BY Class";
        MySqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            chart crt_data = new chart();
            crt_data.Class = dr[0].ToString();
            crt_data.COUNT = Convert.ToInt32(dr[1]);
            chart.Add(crt_data);
        }
        connectionString.Close();
        return chart;
    }
}
```

Actually i am retrieving data through web service but i don't no how to call that web service . I tried like above but i din't get o/p. It simple display empty page. Any one know this how to get web service data.

Comment: Where is your service and how is it defined?  All you've posted is your page and your post function is calling back to the page, which doesn't have a bind_chartvalue method on it.

Comment: i write the service separately not in this code

Comment: Your javascript code `url: 'Ar_PieChart.aspx/bind_chartvalue'` needs to point to the URL of where the service is defined and exposed and not the aspx page.  There's really not enough information in your question to give a definitive answer.

Comment: I need to get web service data and want to print it here as a pie chart and also i tried web service URL but it doesn't work

Comment: You have to post a complete example.  You are not including the web service part of your solution so no one can give you an answer. Please look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to see how to improve your question.

Comment: Ok now i include my service . Please help me

Comment: You are using the temp namespace, which should be your real namespace, the line that says 'uncomment this line to allow being called from script' is still uncommented and your URL will need to point to this service instead of the Page.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the temp namespace, which should be your real namespace, the line that says 'uncomment this line to allow being called from script' is still uncommented and your URL will need to point to this service instead of the Page.aspx.